# BoxWhiskerChart Vertical Line

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have made a box plot to show the spread of past paper results for my A2 exams so I can easily see which subject need more work!

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartLabels->{data[[All,1]]}, BarOrigin->Left, ImageSize->Medium, ChartStyle->Blue]
```

The above code gives me the following output:

[image]

Now, the average for an A is around 61 marks, is there a way to draw a line going from the bottom to top of the chart at the 61 mark limit. This could then give me a better indication of what sort of grade I'm hitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking about online a bit more I found the `Epilog` option. To draw my lines I have added `Epilog->{Directive[{Thick, Red, Dashed}], Line[{{61,0},{61,10}}]}` to the end of the `BoxWhiskerChart` environment.

NB. The 10 in `{60,10}` is the height of the plot with respect to the bars. There are 9 bars plus half either side of the top two, hence 10.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the options `GridLines` and `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
grades = RandomInteger[{30, RandomInteger[{50, 100}]}, {7, 10}];
gridline  = Median[Join @@ grades];
classes = {"Mathematics", "History", "English", "Chemistry", "Law", 
   "Physics", "Statistics"};

BoxWhiskerChart[grades, "Outliers", ChartLabels -> classes,
 BarOrigin -> Left, ChartStyle -> 10, ImageSize -> 500, 
 GridLines -> {{{gridline, Gray}}, None}, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]